# .htaccess rewrite to https, now current and referring servers do not match

Tags: php, .htaccess

In the process of learning PHP and am unsure how to update the following php to account for the .htaccess change of a rewrite to https. Don't believe the current and referring servers to be a match.

```
<?php
if(!class_exists('reg')){
class reg {

    function register($redirect) {
        global $jdb;


        $current = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];


        if ( !empty ( $_POST ) ) {


            if ( $referrer == $current ) {


                $table = 'users';


                $fields = array('name', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'date');


                $values = $jdb->clean($_POST);


                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $date = $_POST['date'];


                $nonce = md5('registration-' . $username . $date . NONCE_SALT);


                $password = $jdb->hash_password($password, $nonce);


                $values = array(
                            'name' => $name,
                            'username' => $username,
                            'password' => $password,
                            'email' => $email,
                            'date' => $date
                        );


                $insert = $jdb->insert($link, $table, $fields, $values);

                if ( $insert == TRUE ) {
                    $url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    $aredirect = str_replace('register.php', $redirect, $url);

                    header("Location: $redirect?reg=true");
                    exit;
                }
            } else {
                die('Your form submission did not come from the correct page. Please check with the site administrator.');
            }
        }
    }
```

Receiving the 'Your form submission did not come from the correct page...' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are saying "$current = 'http://'".

Change this to 'https://' if you site is using SSL.